# Multipart headers seem to be ignored

Tags: groovy, header, multipartform-data

I have the following code which is supposed to send a POST request to some service and basically post a file.

This request is `multipart/form-data`. And it consists of:

- JSON
- Base64 file

The code is below:

```
sendMultipartPost();

def sendMultipartPost() 
{
  def URLToGo = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/sd/services/rest/find/';
  def httpRequest = new HTTPBuilder(URLToGo);
  def authToken = 'AR-JWT ' + 'TOKEN';

  def headers = ['Authorization' : authToken, 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=W3NByNRZZYy4ALu6xeZzvWXU3NVmYUxoRB'];  
  httpRequest.setHeaders(headers);

  def body = ["values":["Incident Number":'testSC',"Work Log Type":"General Information","Description":"File has been added TESTFile","z2AF Work Log01":'Test File title']];

  httpRequest.request(Method.POST) 
  {
      req ->

      MultipartEntity multiPartContent = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, 'W3NByNRZZYy4ALu6xeZzvWXU3NVmYUxoRB', Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

      Gson gson = new Gson(); 
      String jsonObj = gson.toJson(body);

      multiPartContent.addPart('entry', new StringBody(jsonObj, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      multiPartContent.addPart('attach-z2AF Work Log01', new ByteArrayBody(Base64.encodeBase64("let's createBase64 let's createBase64 let's createBase64 let's createBase64 let's createBase64".getBytes()), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, 'test file title'));

      req.setEntity(multiPartContent);

      response.success = { resp ->

          if (resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200) {

                    // response handling

                     }
              }

       response.failure = { resp, json ->
        result = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(['state':resp.status])
          }
  }
}
```

However, whenever I send a request, it seems that some headers are missed or not specified:

[The generated request's body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMBmm.jpg)

But the "perfect" request looks like this:

[The perfect request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f24mZ.jpg)

Now we can conclude that the following headers of JSON:

- `Content-Type` for JSON is missing (although you can see that the first part, which is json, is of `ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON`)
- `charset` is not specified automatically
- `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is not specified automatically

As of base64:

- `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is not specified automatically

Consequently, I have 2 questions:

- Why is the header `Content-Type` of JSON absent whilst I actually set it?
- How do I specify the headers which are not present at all?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Somebody please edit it to show the pictures

Comment: there is no constructor with content type for StringBody. https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/StringBody.html

Comment: No, there's `StringBody(String text, org.apache.http.entity.ContentType contentType)`

Comment: Show the link to documentation.

Comment: The one which you sent.

Comment: No, there's a constructor https://imgur.com/WFdQhQe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the header Content-Type of JSON absent whilst I actually set it?

because you are using `HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE` mode. remove it and you'll get the `content-type` header.

> How do I specify the headers which are not present at all?

the only way in this library - to use `FormBodyPart` to wrap any body and to add required headers.

Here is a code example that you could run in groovyconsole

```groovy
@Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpmime', version='4.5.10')
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody
//import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPartBuilder

//form part has ability to specify additional part headers
def form(Map m){
    def p = FormBodyPartBuilder.create(m.remove('name'), m.remove('body'))
    m.each{ k,v-> p.addField(k,v.toString()) } //all other keys assume to be headers
    return p.build()
}

def json = '{"aaa":111,"bbb":222,"ccc":333}'

def multipart = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addTextBody( "foo", 'bar' ) //transfer text with default encoding
        .addTextBody( "theJson", json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON ) //text with content type
        .addPart(form(
                //add part with headers
                name:'TheJsonWithHdrs', 
                body:new StringBody(json.getBytes("UTF-8").encodeBase64().toString(),ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON), 
                'Content-transfer-encoding':'base64',
            ))
        .build()

//print result
def b = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
multipart.writeTo(b)
println b.toString("ASCII")
```

results

```
--s89LGRZ8HCJ4Gimdis8AH2pXpUQyEpvalzB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

bar
--s89LGRZ8HCJ4Gimdis8AH2pXpUQyEpvalzB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="theJson"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{"aaa":111,"bbb":222,"ccc":333}
--s89LGRZ8HCJ4Gimdis8AH2pXpUQyEpvalzB
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="TheJsonWithHdrs"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

eyJhYWEiOjExMSwiYmJiIjoyMjIsImNjYyI6MzMzfQ==
--s89LGRZ8HCJ4Gimdis8AH2pXpUQyEpvalzB--
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much but unfortunately we can't use that library.

I've changed `HttpMultipartMode` to `HttpMultipartMode.STRICT` and now the headers of the JSON (first multipart) are present! 

However, there's a wrong value for `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header. It's **binary** whilst it should be **base64** or absent...

Please take a look https://imgur.com/a/4uQsED4

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's the same library.. I'm sure you could use it. However, don't use arraybody to send base64 string. Use stringbody with formbody part to be able to specify custom headers

Comment: Ok, the problem is that we don't have `org.apache.ivy.ivy` to use `@Grab`. Is there another way around?

Comment: @Grab - it just to execute it as a simple script. Comment it.

Comment: Thank you very much, the base64 value of the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` was redundant. Just changing to `HttpMultipartMode.STRICT` did the trick!